# Rails on VMware, version 2.3/3 waits 5s before responding, 2.2 is superfast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vmware-workstation

Due to some gems that will only run on *nix, I'm using a VMware 7 vm with Ubuntu 10.4 to run my Rails 3 app, while coding on Windows. One thing I've noticed is that the performance is utterly crap when sending HTTP requests from the host to the guest OS, it takes up to 5 seconds between hitting F5 on the host OS' browser and the request showing up in the Rails console.

Note that I've used clean Rails apps for the testing (`rails testproject` or `rails new testproject`, depending on version) and there is no noticable delay when using Firefox in the VM.

After some testing, I've noticed that when using Rails 2.2(.3) there is no noticable lag either, pretty much ruling out VMware as a cause of this issue.
As I'd much prefer to use Rails 3, I've tried the following;

- A clean VM with Debian/Kubuntu, same result.
- Rails 2.3/3 with specific port/ip to bind to (>2.2 defaults to 0.0.0.0), same result.
- Different VMware connector settings, no difference.
- Different Ruby versions (1.8.6, 1.9.1, 1.9.2-head), no difference.

Google didn't offer much help here, hopefully serverfault will; what can I possibly try to get rid of this 5s delay in every request?

Comment: This may be way off base but the type of issue seems remarkably similar to an ipv6 issue I used to see with Firefox and Chrome OS - the real root cause was a broken ipv6 dns proxying, once I fixed that all the problems went away.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, though ipv6 seems to work perfectly. I've set up Apache/Passenger now, which is running awesomely fast as well. A bit weird, but will do just fine for now.

Comment: Fair enough - the 5 second delay in the browser is a common signature of this ipv6 DNS resolver issue. Just to be clear, ipv6 isn't broken on systems that have this problem - the problem is with the response or lack of one) from an ipv4 DNS that isn't handling AAAA (ipv6) requests properly.